# How to subtract all elements in list from one element in another list?

Tags: python, list, loops, nested, subtraction

I have a problem with mathematically subtracting all elements of one list against one element of another list.
This is what I need:

```
>>>list1 = [ a, b, c]
>>>list2 = [ d, e, f]    

result = [ d-a, e-a, f-a, d-b, e-b, f-b, d-c, e-c, f-c]
```

I tried with a nested loop for but it doesn' t work out just fine:

```
 subtr = [] 
 for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
       subtr.append(j - i)
```

If someone could please help I would be very thankful!

Comment: Your code works fine.What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [10, 20, 30]

result = [x-y for y in list1 for x in list2]
```

Result:

```
[9, 19, 29, 8, 18, 28, 7, 17, 27]
```

Comment: Thx very much! I figured out Pycharm was just cutting the list when I printed it and not displaying the expected solution (I am new to Python). Thx anyway very much, very useful!

Answer (score 4):

With list comprehensions and example values

```
list1 = [ 10, 20, 30]
list2 = [ 1, 2, 3] 

[y - x for x in list1 for y in list2]
```

Out:

```
[-9, -8, -7, -19, -18, -17, -29, -28, -27]
```

---

Your code does the same. You can test it with example values

```
subtr = [] 
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        subtr.append(j - i)
print(subtr)
```

Out:

```
[-9, -8, -7, -19, -18, -17, -29, -28, -27]
```

Comment: Thx very much! I figured out Pycharm was just cutting the list when I printed it and not displaying the expected solution (I am new to Python). Thx anyway very much, very useful!